# Why isn't my Postgres index being used?

Tags: postgresql, performance, index

I’m using Postgres 9.5.  I want to create indexes that will make queries like

```
select * FROM my_object_times where name like ‘Dave %’;
```

and

```
select * FROM my_object_times where name like '% LastName';
```

run quickly.  So I created …

```
CREATE INDEX my_object_times_name_idx ON my_object_times (name text_pattern_ops);
CREATE INDEX my_object_times_rev_name_idx ON my_object_times (reverse(name) text_pattern_ops);
```

This works fine for the first case, in which I can see my index being used, but in the second case, “Explain” does not show my index being utilized …

```
my_db=> explain select * FROM my_object_times where name like '% LastName';
                            QUERY PLAN                            
------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on my_object_times  (cost=0.00..136594.69 rows=51 width=221)
   Filter: ((name)::text ~~ '% LastName'::text)
```

How do I get my index to be in used in the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer, because you're not reversing it in the query, and that's not implicit.**

```
SELECT * FROM my_object_times where reverse(name) like reverse('% LastName');
```

However, that's **a horrible idea.** Instead delete both of those indexes. If you have to have non-anchored matching on something like "LastName" try [the pgtrgm extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) which will just work on `LIKE` and `%`. Tell us how it goes.

Install pg_trgm,

```
CREATE extention pg_trgm;
```

Create either a gist or gin index.

```
CREATE index test_trgm_gin ON test USING gin (some_text gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE index test_trgm_gist ON test USING gist (some_text gist_trgm_ops);
```

See [this blog post on depesz](https://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/) for more information.

Why is two `text_pattern_ops` an inferior idea,

1. Two `text_pattern_ops` will never support `'%foo%'`
2. Not likely any library even supports this manual `reverse()` of all conditions.

   - What do I mean? Most ORM's support assembling a where clause from a hash. Here is an example for [Sequalize,](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/querying/). `{LastName: { $like: '% LastName' } }` It's unlikely that this is going to ever generate, `reverse(LastName) LIKE reverse('% LastName')`. So the index simply won't be used unless you write it all manually: at best, that will obfuscate your use of a third party tool, at worst it'll be impossible or very difficult to make work. Where as the `pg_trgm` option just works.
3. Requires the user to know something of the index-implementation.
4. I'm not sure it's more space-efficient than GIST, or faster than either.

Also, as another note, if it just comes down to size you can always get another hard drive, set it up as a `TABLESPACE` and store the GIST index there. That doesn't solve the /space/ problem, but it should mitigate it.

Comment: I'll tell you how its going -- I already have a trgm index but that takes up a TON of disk space and since my queries are not of the form like "%something%", I figured I'd tried a more space-efficient approach.  Why do you say "However, that's a horrible idea."?

Comment: @Dave updated with information.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification.  One last question about point #2 -- what do you mean "reverse() of all conditions"?

Comment: @Dave if you could get back to us with what you find works. I'd love to see the size of the GIST index with the two text_pattern_ops, `\di+ table_name*`

Comment: Posterity may want to note for #4, in my table with 39M rows, the trgm index took up 13.6 GB of space but with the two other indexes it only takes up 2.4 GB.  So since points #1, #2, and #3 don't apply to me, I've found a winner.

Comment: Wow, that's a huge difference. I'm impressed. Glad to hear it worked out.